# __dirname being set during compile with pkg, rather than during runtime

Tags: node.js

Pretty much the title, after using PKG to compile my node.js app my variable that uses __dirname is being set to my computer's paths, rather than when I run the exe. This leads to issues whenever I distribute my app to users it won't work for them. Anyone have a fix or a workaround?